# JPA repository - improve findAll() performances

Tags: java, mysql, jpa

I am using JPA repository, I need to retrieve a whole Mysql table(40000 records) wich has 5 foreign keys towards smaller tables (500 records). I need one field of each of these 5 tables.

If I call a JPArepository `findall()`, it takes a few seconds to retrieve all the data.

I need it to be faster. Is there a way to do that?

I don't know what would be the best solution, if it can be done on mysql side, or must be done on Java side.
All the tables are  well mapped to JPA entities :

```
@Entity
    @Table(name = "T_CLIENT")
    @Cache(usage = CacheConcurrencyStrategy.NONSTRICT_READ_WRITE)
    public class Client implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;

    @Column(name = "code")
    private String code;

    @OneToOne
    private Seller seller;

    @OneToOne
    private Language language;

    @OneToOne
    private Address address;

    @OneToOne
    private Country billCountry;

    @OneToOne
    private ClientType clientType;
}
```

Thank you for your answers.

Comment: maybe you shouldnt use `findAll()` if you need to only 5 fields, then retrieve only them.

Comment: Consider unidirectional associations using @JoinTable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can choose loading fields from foreign keys tables using [EntityGraph](http://www.javacodegeeks.com/2014/05/jpa-2-1-entity-graph-part-2-define-lazyeager-loading-at-runtime.html) mechanism.